# How to flatten a multi-dimension array in JQ

Tags: json, jq

I have the following JSON:

```
{
  "accounts": [
    {
      "group": 1,
      "users": [
        {
          "name": "John",
          "id": 1
        },
        {
          "name": "Jane",
          "id": 2
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "group": 2,
      "users": [
        {
          "name": "Bob",
          "id": 3
        },
        {
          "name": "Mary",
          "id": 3
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like the output to look like this:

```
{
  "accounts": [
    {
      "group": 1,
      "name": "John",
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "group": 1,
      "name": "Jane",
      "id": 2
    },
    {
      "group": 2,
      "name": "Bob",
      "id": 3
    },
    {
      "group": 2,
      "name": "Mary",
      "id": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

How do I use `jq` to accomplish this?

I would like an object:

1. with the key "accounts"
2. elements with "group", "name", "id"

So far I have tried `jq --raw-output '.accounts[].group, .accounts[].users[].name, .accounts[].users[].id'`, but it gives me the following:

```
1
2
John
Jane
Bob
Mary
1
2
3
3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add each item of the `.users` array to the single `{group}` item. Do it for all items in the `.accounts` array using `map`, and do it in place using an update-assignment `|=`:

```bash
jq '.accounts |= map({group} + .users[])' file.json
```

```json
{
  "accounts": [
    {
      "group": 1,
      "name": "John",
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "group": 1,
      "name": "Jane",
      "id": 2
    },
    {
      "group": 2,
      "name": "Bob",
      "id": 3
    },
    {
      "group": 2,
      "name": "Mary",
      "id": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/Qm_FVWQ9z6r)